# постоянно в счётчике слов выводит какую - то чушь перепробовал массу вариантов но результат один и тот же

Tags: c, текст, работа-с-текстом

[image: проблема с выводом.]

постоянно в счётчике слов выводит какую - то чушь перепробовал массу вариантов но результат один и тот же.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 3):

а вы специально не значение переменной `word` выводите, а ссылку на переменную `word` (по сути адрес переменной)?

```
print("%d", &word);
```

попробуйте

```
print("%d", word);
```